# DB-Library and ESQL/C (for educational purposes)

Tags: sql-server, embedded-sql

Understanding old technologies often help us to better understand new ones, so this is a question to the gurus of database programming with many years of experience (since the very beginning of SQL Server, at least version 6.5).

Recently I've searched MS TechNet seeking for old methods of access databases and I found [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa225194%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).

As you can see, when comparing DB-Library with ESQL/C they say:

***«... The call-level method of programming requires no precompiler; however, you cannot include Transact-SQL statements in your C programs, as you can with Embedded SQL for C (ESQL/C) ...»***

AFAIK, ESQL/C is a wrapper around DB-library.

So, if DB-Library can't do Transact-SQL how can ESQL/C do?

Can someone point out to me what I'm not following?